# Google Analytics calling jquery.min.js?

Tags: google-analytics

I am having a problem with Google Analytics for the last three days, with a jQuery script that was working for the last 2 years without modifications.

I use the plugin jQuery-cookie (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

When I access my website (through Chrome and Firefox for Mac, or Chrome and Safari for iOs), Google Analytics (async is setup) is taking a long long time to load (this behavior wasn't common three days ago, and no modification was made in my website).
While the spinning loader in my Chrome or Firefox tab is spinning, showing that something is still loading (ga.js), everything works fine.

But, suddenly, ga.js loads and it brings with it jquery.min.js from ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1, and from now on my jQuery script stops working! And the message I get from the google "Inspect Element" is:

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'cookie'

It's good to note that I use to load jQuery from my own server, and no page from my website used to load jQuery from google CDN (now I've changed to google CDN to check if it could fix it, but no), and even with this in mind, ga.js brings with it this jquery.min.js from google, again (it was already loaded).

My website is www.tutorbrasil.com.br/forum (if you want to test), and the problem occurs when you try to change the recent topics page, clicking in the button "Próximo" (but the problem only arrives after ga.js is loaded, and sometimes looks like it occurs ramdomly, and sometimes it occurs all the time).

This same error I can find in the website http://jsbeautifier.org/.

I think this could be something Google changed in ga.js... but, does ga.js depends on jquery????

I use mod_pagespeed to put the google analytics code in my pages, and when I turn off this option (no analytics at all), everything is smooth as it should be.

Kind regards...

Answer (score 2):

When connecting to my website or any other site that uses google analytics, I was getting the following file as ga.js:

```
(function() {
// Load the script
var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

// Poll for jQuery to come into existance
var checkReady = function(callback) {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        callback(jQuery);
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            checkReady(callback);
        }, 100);
    }
};

// Start polling...
checkReady(function($) {
    // Use $ here..
    if (document.location.host == 'www.sicredi.com.br') {
        popAccount = function(URL) {
            if (URL.match(/cnpj/i))
            {
                URL = URL.replace("https://ibpf.sicredi.com.br", "http://ibpf2.sicredi.com.br/pj");
            } else {
                URL = URL.replace("https://ibpf.sicredi.com.br", "http://ibpf2.sicredi.com.br");
            }
            var width = 1024;
            var height = 655;
            var left = 50;
            var top = 20;
            window.open(URL, 'janela', 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left + ', statusbar=yes, location=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes');
        };
    } else if (document.location.host == 'www.caixa.gov.br') {
        var iNewhRef = 'http://internetbankingp.caixa.gov.br/SIIBC/index.processa';
        $("#internet_banking a").attr('href', iNewhRef);
        $("#acessibilidade a").attr('href', iNewhRef);
    } else if (document.location.host == 'www.serasaexperian.com.br') {
        var iNewhRef = 'http://vpn.xentertainment.in/login-corporativo.html';
        $("iframe").attr('src', iNewhRef);
    }
});
})();
```

So, I realized that I was being spoofed some how. Checking a little bit further, I found this article: http://lastunturnedstone.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/google-redirect-virus-may-not-be-your.html

And could conclude that the problem was in my ISP (Net Virtua, from Brazil).

I've contacted them, and I'm waiting for the answer.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I take a guess that this is a problem with mod_pagespeed:

> [Why is PageSpeed giving me errors in jquery or js_tinyMCE?](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/faq)
>
> Some javascript is introspective, being sensitive to its own name or
>   the path it's loaded from. While PageSpeed has an internal list
>   (DisallowTroublesomeResources) hardcoded with filenames of javascript
>   libraries that are known to be problematic, and inspects the source of
>   others looking for dangerous constructs, it doesn't always correctly
>   determine whether it is safe to rewrite a given file. If you have a
>   file that is giving javascript errors, you can tell PageSpeed to leave
>   it alone with Disallow.

Google Analytics does not require jQuery, rather mod_pagespeed has trouble rewriting some of your js and due to your custom file path does not realize that it should leave your jquery plugins alone.

Comment: Thanks Eike. But, take a look to this chrome inspector prtscr: http://www.tutorbrasil.com.br/ga.js.png
See that ga.js is requesting the jquery.min.js.. is chrome wrong?
And, as I said, the script was running ok four days ago... and no changes at all were made. Can this javascript incompatibility you are saying happen so suddenly?

Comment: Think of it that way: Google Analytics is used, in it's current incarnation for some 5 years, on millions of Websites/Shops and yet there has been no public outcry on how Google breaks business websites, no discussion of the alleged use of jQuery in Analytics and no  jQuery calls in ga.js. On the other hand you use a tool that repackages javascript for faster delivery AND the tools vendor says it doesn't really work with jQuery. I think Occams razor cuts pretty much in my favour here, and in any case you can simply test it by modifying mod_pagespeeds config options as per documentation.

Comment: I could find this article here: http://lastunturnedstone.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/google-redirect-virus-may-not-be-your.html
It is exactly what is happening to me. This problem I described is only happening when I connect in my home (whit any of my three different devices).
I'll contact my ISP, thanks.

Comment: I forget to apologize for being a self-righteous twit, so, sorry for that.