# Google Analytics injecting jQuery 1.7 after page load

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having an issue with the old google Analytics tracking code (property hasn't been updated) where this Google Analytics code:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

is injecting "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" right before my closing head tag on page load, which causes all my jQuery down the line to break - as I'm already loading jQuery higher up in the head.

I've been googling for an hour with no answer as to why this is going on, but as far as i can tell every site i run using the old Google Analytics properties has this, so it doesn't seem to be a bug/hack.

But, how can i stop google from loading up this extraneous jQuery?

Edit #1:
i *believe* the first answer here is the answer to my problem, but will wait to see if anyone has a better answer:

[Google Analytics calling jquery.min.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030816/google-analytics-calling-jquery-min-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this problem was in fact an ISP problem, as another recent SO question got to:

[Google Analytics calling jquery.min.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030816/google-analytics-calling-jquery-min-js)

The issue was in fact coming from a spoofed ga.js file that was adding the jQuery post page load. A quick call to the ISP had them finding the problem and correcting it.

A detailed blog post on the issue, from Costa Rica, can be found here:
http://lastunturnedstone.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/google-redirect-virus-may-not-be-your.html

Hopefully this helps anyone with the problem in the future -